# Weird Problems while trying to use a attendance system via VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6, ocx

I am playing with a fingerprint controlled attendance system.

( http://www.ocomtech.com/product_info-97.html )

I searched for its SDK and found one for VB6

( http://www.ocom.cn/uploads/download/OTA710C_SDK(VB).rar )

After a lot of efforts, i managed to use Fkattend.ocx in my app.

I also managed to connect to device, get time/date data

Now, when i wish to read some data from a object:

`long GetEnrollData(long anEnrollNumber, long anBackupNumber, long
*apnMachinePrivilege, long *apnEnrollData, long *apnPassWord)`

It always keeps on acting wierd. Sometimes raise an `AccessViolation` exception.

**EDIT:**

The Error that keeps on repeating from time to time:

> The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error
>   was at 0x6f4fcfa3, on thread 0x128c. The error code is 0xc0000005.
>   This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable
>   portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user
>   marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the
>   stack.

The questions are:

1. Is it because i am trying to use a ocx designed for VB6 in VB.NET? Do VB6 ocx run fine on VB.NET?
2. This isn't right place to ask this question but: If anyone has ever used fkattend.dll,  Would you share why this may happen?

Comment: Check the params. "Long" in vb6 was 32 bit, now in .net it is 64 bit. Common mistake ...

Comment: @igrimpe : Changed long to int and int to short. no effect. BTW, see the edit

Comment: @cipher did you get this solved? And have you found a .net sdk?